# A continous map between the two torus and the torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\Sigma$ be the doubled torus (a compact oriented) surface of genus 2) and let $T$ be the torus. Suppose $f: \Sigma \rightarrow T$. Prove that $f$ is not a local homeomorphism.

Attempt at solution: Suppose $f$ was a local homeomorphism. Then by this exercise [A Local Homeomorphism Between Compact Connected Hausdorff Topological Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898655/a-local-homeomorphism-between-compact-connected-hausdorff-topological-spaces) 
it would be a covering map. Covering maps induce an injection from the fundamental group of the covering to that of the base. However, for the doubled torus, the fundamental group is given by $\langle a,b,c,d\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}\rangle$ while that of the torus is $\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$, hence no such injection can exist.

Comment: the number of holes (genus of surface) is topological invariant, as such any continuous map from 2-torus to 1-torus would necessarily *swallow* one of the holes of the 2-torus

Comment: @NikosM., what do you mean by "topological invariant"? I generally hear this term used for things that are invariant under homeomorphism, but not necessarily under all continuous maps. For example, the map from any topological space to the one-point space is always continuous, but it doesn't preserve the number of connected components, which is a topological invariant.

Comment: @Vectornautm yes exactly invariant under homeomorphisms which i think is what is meant in the question by continuous map

Comment: @NikosM. A *local* homeomorphism is quite different from a homeomorphism, and many topological invariants, like the number of connected components and the Euler characteristic, are not invariant under local homeomorphism.

Comment: @Vectornaut, thanx, i missed that part!

Answer (score 4):

If you have the machinery of the Euler characteristic available, you can use the fact that if $f$ were an $n$-fold covering map, the Euler characteristic of $\Sigma$ would have to be $n$ times the Euler characteristic of $T$.